# determining the IP from which an mysql connect (PDO) request came from

Tags: mysql

I want one Linux server to get or put data to the MySQL server on another Linux machine.  I want to avoid granting

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@% IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

but instead would like to do:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to root@123.123.123.123 ..
```

where 123.. is the IP of the server that is making the request.  Where would I go to get a log of the request made on the receiving database end, to know what IP is being queried from?  I don't know enough about networking to know this, or to be sure which IP is being used.

Also, would it be OK to use a hostname of the querying server, or is that slower due to DNS lookup time?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what IP you're connecting from:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

This will show the originating IP. You can tighten your rules accordingly.

Comment: but I do that and see two processes - one is the show processlist command itself, the other is the root process - I don't see any history of previous processes - ANYWAY - it appears that once I removed bind = 127.0.0.1 in my.cnf, it told me the IP that it saw me as - which was the server main IP.

Comment: If you were bound to the local interface you probably wouldn't be able to connect remotely.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment to @tadman, the problem turned out to be that I had

```
bind = 127.0.0.1
```

in the my.conf file found in /etc/mysql.

Well, once I disabled and restarted mysql, mysql came back and said "permission denied to root@____" - but then I was able to know the IP address.  Predictably I guess, it was the primary DNS IP for that server.  But problem solved because I was able to set that permission on the remote.